# Check if dynamically created richtextbox not in focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms

if creating a dictionary program. when use copy some text on clipboard it will give the meanings of copied text in a form visible on system try. i want to close the form when user click any where on his/her screen. but if user want to copy some text from meanings from will not close i added more then one dynamically created richtextboxes in a tab control to show number of meanings. my code is working great accept one thing when user scroll the richtextboxes form will close itself. it seems scrollbars are not the part of richtextbox. Help me to solve this problem my code is below.

```
Dim s As Boolean = True

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If MouseButtons.ToString = "Left" Or MouseButtons.ToString = "Right" Then
        If s = True Then
            If InStr(LCase(Me.ActiveControl.ToString), LCase("Label")) Then
                Me.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub frmdict_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
    s = False
    Button1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub frmdict_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
    s = True
    Label1.Focus()
End Sub
```

**==Update==**

i have form1 which contains this code to add richtextboxes and tabs to tabcontrl

```
Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
Dim myrichtext As New RichTextBox()
myrichtext.Name = "RichTextBox" & i
myTabPage.Text = StrSearch & i
frmdict.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)
myTabPage.Controls.Add(myrichtext)
myrichtext.RightToLeft = Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No
myrichtext.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
myrichtext.Font = New Font("Urdulink", 14)
```

And finally open frmdict to show meaning

```
If frmdict.TabControl1.TabPages.Count > 0 Then
  frmdict.TabControl1.RightToLeftLayout = True
  frmdict.Show()
  frmdict.Label1.Focus()
  ' frmdict.TabControl1.Focus()
Else
  frmdict.Close()
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MouseLeave` does fire whenever the mouse goes over one of the child controls of the form, which is probably not what you were expecting.

I'm not sure what's going on with your label and button, but something like this will probably make it work for you:

```
If s = True Then
  If Not rtb1.Bounds.Contains(Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) AndAlso _
     TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is Label Then
    Me.Close()
  End If
End If
```

**Update:**

In terms of your dynamic rich text controls, you don't really need the name.  Something like this should work (not completely tested):

```
If TabControl1.SelectedTab IsNot Nothing Then
  For Each rtb As RichTextBox In TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType(Of RichTextBox)()
    If Not rtb.Bounds.Contains(rtb.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) Then
      Me.Close()
    End If
  Next
End If
```

Comment: it is a dictionary program and i multiple richtextboxes which are dynamically created so i don't know there names. And thery are embedded in a tabl control so iam unable to get their names.

Comment: @user934820 Do you mean all of the RTF controls are in a TableLayoutPanel control?